# Carry forward a Hot Spot Question's selected regions in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I was trying to find a way to carry forward all the selected regions in a previous hot spot question to a new question, i.e. set the default selected regions in the new question to be the same as the answer question.

It seems that I can access the value of regions for the answered question, e.g. `${q://QID33/ChoiceGroup/SelectedAnswers/7}`.

But I'm not sure how to select the default regions in the new question using Javascript.

Any idea?